# retrieve html data with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function

so i have this line of code in my html

```
    <td class="product-price">
        <span class="amount" id="price">3915.00</span> 
    </td>
```

how can i that number "3915.00" in my javascript as an integer?

```
    <script>
    function myFunction()
        {     
            var priceStr = document.getElementById('price').value;
            var priceInt = parseInt(price);              
        }

    </script>
```

can i do it this way? or are there any alternatives?

Comment: span does not have a value property. get it's "textContent" and parse that into an INT, or FLOAT in your case.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `innerHTML` or `textContent`

```js
function myFunction() {
  var priceStr = document.getElementById('price').innerHTML;
  var priceInt = parseInt(priceStr);
  return priceInt;
}

alert(myFunction());
```

```html
<td class="product-price">
  <span class="amount" id="price">3915.00</span>
</td>
```

Comment: It's good to note that parseInt will return NaN if the first character cannot be converted to a number

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the price does not come from js in the first place, this is an ok way to get it from the html.

Here is a fixed version of your function though:

```
function myFunction()
        {     
            return parseInt(document.getElementById('price').innerHTML);    
        }
```